# Android edittext change popup context menu style

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-support-library, android-theme, android-styles

I want to change `EditText` popup context menu background when long click the `EditText`.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work. The popup context menu background still not changed.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyPopupStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The result I want is, popup context menu background is the same as accent color which is magenta. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Hey I faced similar question (but what I wanted is to change the text color). Did you solved this issue at last?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code Outcome]My theme:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/popup_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#512DA8</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/popup_background</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/popup_background</item>
        **<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/popup_background</item>**
    </style>

<resources>
    <color name="window_background">#FFF5F5F5</color>
    <color name="popup_background">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Using popup context menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
        PopupMenu menu  = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        MenuInflater inflater = menu.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.drawer_view, menu.getMenu());
        menu.show();
        return false;

    }
```

[image]

Will it possible if you can share your code for popup?

Comment: Before I posted my question, I already tried the attribute `actionModeBackground`, but it didn't work. I think the popup context menu is different with the action mode menu.

Comment: Thanks very much, the result showed in your image is the action mode context menu, which is appeared in action bar. The result I want is changing the popup context menu style which is **NOT** appear in action bar.